# How to install additional languages to PHP

Tags: php, centos, locale

I have been hosting my PHP Sites on Windows Servers for years and I've always had the german locales (de-DE and de-AT) installed. They've sometimes been called different (as you can see at one of my other questions) but I've always had them available. However, I am now hosting on a dedicated server with CentOS 6.6 and I have no idea how I can get the german locale.

I'd really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140299/locale-gen-command-in-centos6

Comment: Thanks for that comment. It lead me to another post that mentioned to try 

locale -a 

that showed that german is installed in any variants, yet it's not available in PHP. Any ideas why?